# iTextSharp table layout problems

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm having problems creating a particular layout in iTextSharp using tables.

I begin the document by creating a table that splits the page in two, and in each of these columns I then insert an additional table with x rows and 1 column each.

The reason I want to do it like this is because I want a layout resembling [this HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/jML2Q/1/).

But what is happening is the following:

[image]

The tables which as per the code are independent seem linked together.

**OLD CODE**

```
private void AddBody()
    {
        Image smallerLogo = Image.GetInstance(_logo);
        smallerLogo.ScaleAbsolute(100f, 100f);

        Image normalLogo = Image.GetInstance(_logo);

        ExtendedTable table = new ExtendedTable(2, 1, true, false, true);
        table.SetWidths(new[] { 50, 50 });

        ExtendedTable col1 = new ExtendedTable(1, 6, true, false, false);
        col1.AddCell(new ExtendedCell(new Chunk("Impressions", _headingFont), false));
        col1.AddCell(new ExtendedCell(smallerLogo, false));
        col1.AddCell(new ExtendedCell(new Chunk("Visitor funnel", _headingFont), false));
        col1.AddCell(new ExtendedCell(smallerLogo, false));
        col1.AddCell(new ExtendedCell(new Chunk("Shortlists", _headingFont), false));
        col1.AddCell(new ExtendedCell(smallerLogo, false));

        ExtendedTable col2 = new ExtendedTable(1, 6, true, false, false);
        col2.AddCell(new ExtendedCell(new Chunk("Leads", _headingFont), false));
        col2.AddCell(new ExtendedCell(normalLogo, false));
        col2.AddCell(new ExtendedCell(new Chunk("Demographics", _headingFont), false));
        col2.AddCell(new ExtendedCell(normalLogo, false));

        table.AddCell(new ExtendedCell(col1, false));
        table.AddCell(new ExtendedCell(col2, false));

        _document.Add(table);
    }
```

**NEW CODE**

```
private void AddBody()
    {
        Image smallerLogo = Image.GetInstance(_logo);
        smallerLogo.ScaleAbsolute(60.0f, 60.0f);

        Image normalLogo = Image.GetInstance(_logo);

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.SetWidths(new[] { 50, 50 });

        PdfPTable col1 = new PdfPTable(1);
        col1.AddCell("Impressions");
        col1.AddCell(new PdfPCell(smallerLogo));
        col1.AddCell("Visitor funnel");
        col1.AddCell(new PdfPCell(smallerLogo));
        col1.AddCell("Shortlists");
        col1.AddCell(new PdfPCell(smallerLogo));

        PdfPTable col2 = new PdfPTable(1);
        col2.AddCell("Leads");
        col2.AddCell(normalLogo);
        col2.AddCell("Demographics");
        col2.AddCell(normalLogo);

        table.AddCell(col1);
        table.AddCell(col2);

        _document.Add(table);
    }
```

Where `ExtendedCell` and `ExtendedTable` are small classes that remove the table borders.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you convert your code to just use `PdfPTable` and `PdfCell`? I know they're just simple wrappers but it would really help us if we could just use the basic objects for troubleshooting. Specifically, the constructors are a little hard to diagnose.

Comment: Thanks Chris.. it appears that your suggestion to use the PdfP classes has fixed my problem. What is the difference between `iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable` and `iTextSharp.text.Table`?

Comment: (I think that the problem that I was experiencing was the result of using the `Table` and not `PdfPTable`)

Comment: First this: if you are using the `Table` class, you're using a mighty old version of iTextSharp because the `Table` class was removed from iTextSharp years ago. You should upgrade! Also: if you want to organize content in columns, you should try the `ColumnText` object. It's well documented and it allows you to put any content at any position on the page.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thanks for clarifying that Bruno. I thought there was something odd about having two versions of what appeared to do the same thing in the lib!